Is it possible to typecast interface object at runtime in Java using dependency injection?
public interface Animal {
    void speak();
}

public class Dog implements Animal{
    void speak (){
        System.out.println("This is dog.")
    }
}

public class Cat implements Animal{
    void speak (){
        System.out.println("This is cat.")
    }
}


@Module
public class Module{

    @Provides
    @Named("Dog")
        static Animal providesDog() {
            return new Dog();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("Cat")
        static Animal providesCat() {
            return new Cat();
        }
}

public class AnimalOrchestrator {

    @Inject
    Animal animal;

    public void speak(String type) {

        if(type.equals("dog")
            (Dog) animal.speak();
        else
            (Cat) animal.speak();

    }
}

Is such kind of typecasting possible where at runtime we determining which Dog/Cat object should Animal object translate as?
Following are some other ways using which such a functionality is achieved.
public class AnimalOrchestrator {

    @Inject
    Dog dog;

    @Inject
    Cat cat;

    public void speak(String type) {

        if(type.equals("dog")
            dog.speak();
        else
            cat.speak();

    }
}

The above code has the disadvantage that we need to create objects of dog and cat both although only one of the above will be used.
Another way is the following:
public class AnimalOrchestrator {

    Animal animal;

    public void speak(String type) {

        if(type.equals("dog"){
            animal = new Dog();
            animal.speak();
        } else {
            animal = new Cat();
            animal.speak();
        }
    }
}

With this, We have to create this object using new operator that i wanted to avoid so as to leverage dependency injection.
Is the first solution even possible? If yes, which among these is better?

Welcome to StackOverflow. The short answer is no, you cannot cast an instance of a class into another class unless it is a superclass. On a broader scale, it is unclear to me what you are aiming at here. Your second snippet with the working example is perfectly fine. If you would like to "optimize" the code, then this is probably not the performance improvement you are looking for. Moreover, for such a simple example you could skip polymorphism entirely and log the lines directly from speak(String type)

The speak method on AnimalOrchestrator could be called at different times with different values for type, so it needs to have access to both instances.

What would you expect to be the result of this code?  Where is the decision being made about which of these to inject?

What are you trying to do? Any code with if(type.equals("dog") or instanceof smells like you should replace conditional with polymorphism but you are already doing that, so it's unclear why you need type checking... just call whatever method on the injected animal? Maybe I just don't understand what you are doing here.

I am trying to control what animal object should be created at runtime based what type i pass through the AnimalOrchestrator Class.
ie: if I call, AnimalOrchestrator.speak("Dog"), it should print "This is dog", but if I call, AnimalOrchestrator.speak("Cat"), it should print "This is cat"

@TamasHegedus As you mentioned, " you cannot cast an instance of a class into another class unless it is a superclass", So if i make Animal as an abstract class instead of an interface and let Dog and Cat, extend the Animal class, will we be able to achieve the polymorphism?
PS: the actual functionality is not that simple. I have tried to create an analogy for better understanding.

The ask is to have some kind of lazy initialization at runtime based on the parameter passed

Before answering this question I should notice that I did not used @Inject Annotation however I think the code can be used with it.
Now the thing you are asking for is Composite Pattern.
By using a type variable to determine which animal is cat or dog you violate Open/Closed principle. Your code is open for modification. Everytime when you need a new animal in the future you are going to add new type checking code. That means your AnimalOrchestrator gonna change a lot and potentially will cause bugs too many times.
Now the answer is like this;
public interface Animal {
    void speak();
}


public class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("This is Cat");
    }

}


public class Dog implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("This is Dog");
    }

}


public class Mammals implements Animal {

    private List<Animal> animalList;
    
    public Mammals(Animal... animals){
        this.animalList = Arrays.asList(animals);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        for(Animal animal : this.animalList){
            animal.speak();
        }
        
        System.out.println("This is Mammals");
    }

}


public class Main {

    static Dog dog = new Dog();


    static Cat cat = new Cat();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mammals mammals = new Mammals(cat, dog);
        mammals.speak();
    }
}

Note that your AnimalOrchestrator class is being my Mammals class in this manner
